# Retrieving data from Google APIs and populate twice

Tags: php, arrays, api, charts

I need your help because I'm stuck on how to get secondary datas from Google API and show them on a graph, let me explain :

I've successfully retrieved "visits" datas from the Google Analytics API and show them on my chart with this code :

```
                $report3 = $ga->getReport(
                array('dimensions'=>urlencode('ga:date'),
                    'metrics'=>urlencode('ga:pageviews,ga:visits'),
                    'filters'=>urlencode(''),
                    'sort'=>'ga:date'
                    )
                );
```

Which give me an array like :

```
[20110726] => Array
    (
        [ga:pageviews] => 0
        [ga:visits] => 0
    )
```

Then I put these informations on the chart with :

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var ga_data = [
    <?php
        $str = "";
        foreach ($report3 as $value)
            $str.="{$value["ga:visits"]},";
        $str = rtrim($str,",");
    echo $str;
    ?>
    ];
</script>
```

And finally :

```
      // Create the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
data.addColumn('number', 'visits');
data.addRows(ga_data.length*1);
for (i=9; i<ga_data.length; i++){

    data.setValue(i, 0, 'DATE NEEDED');
    data.setValue(i, 1, ga_data[i]);
}
```

The only problem is that I need to show the DATE : (`[20110726] => Array
    (
        [ga:pageviews] => 0
        [ga:visits] => 0
    )`) on the chart like I do with visits

Any help will be very very appreciated ! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data coming back has the date as the index of the array (a.k.a. 'Dimension'). Just update your loop to get that like so.

```
foreach(ga_data as $date=>$values){
    data.setValue(i, 0, $date);
    data.setValue(i, 1, $values['ga:visits']);
}
```

You might need to split the date into its parts if the DataVisualization API can't handle that type like so:

```
$str = '20110726';
$year = substr($str,0,4);
$month = substr($str,4,2);
$day = substr($str,6,2);
```

Then format to your liking with the PHP date() function.